# selecting the correct target when creating a new WKInterfaceController

Tags: xcode, watchkit, watchos-2

Normally when you create a new WKInterfaceController you just select the WKInterfaceController class and Swift/Obj-C. But the next screen gives you 3 options for choosing the target; iOS app, WatchKit App and WatchKit Extension. It is defaulting to the iOS app for me so I am concerned that maybe I selected the wrong targets for my previous classes.

1. How do you know what target to select? Is it usually always the WatchKit Extension since that's what we're obviously putting our classes in? It seems obvious I know but I want to make sure because I often get confused with what targets to add binaries, classes and everything else to.
2. If I have made a mistake in choosing the target for a new WKInterfaceController.swift file where do I fix it? Would I fix it in Build Phases -> Compile Sources?

Apple says [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CustomzingthePushNotificationInterface.html) when creating a ***WKUserNotificationInterfaceController*** to add it to the WatchKit Extension target. But does that apply to our own custom ***WKInterfaceController*** classes as well?

[image]

Comment: You should have been able to easily determine the answer by creating a new watch app project, selecting an interface controller, and examining which target it belonged to, either via the Project Navigator group, or the Utilities File Inspector pane.

Comment: Yes but I didn't know if Xcode had selected that target based on my last choice. As you know sometimes applications auto select choices based on your previous selection/action. I couldn't be sure in this case even with a new project there is no guarantee that is the default choice so I had to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You'd add it to the WatchKit Extension.

   Notification controller, glance controllers, complication controllers, and interface controllers all run in the extension.

   > [An interface controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceController) runs in your WatchKit extension and remotely manages the behavior associated with an interface controller in your Watch app’s storyboard file.
2. If you made a mistake and added it to the wrong group, you'd correct it in that same (Utilities File Inspector) pane, by simply unchecking the wrong target, then checking the proper target.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

If I start adding a file by double clicking on the WatchKit Extension, then it defaults to choosing the WatchKit Extension for the location of the file.  Do you perhaps choose New File from the top menu?  It probably doesn't default then.

So yes, you should add WatchKit user interface classes like this to the WatchKit Extension.

As to 2), you can change file membership in the file properties on the right pane, using the File Inspector.  You'll see a Target Membership check box there.  This will change membership, but as I remember it will not move the file on disk, so just be aware of that if you do it this way.